# Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted - Agian

Tags: php, jquery

I have code which downloads a picture from a fake link. I have looked at others comments / sites but nothing has helped me find the solution to the annoying :

"Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted"

my php headers are after I read the GET value:

```
header("Pragma: public"); // required 
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
//header('Content-Length: '. @filesize($id));
header('Content-Type: '.$mim);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$date.basename($fileName).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
readfile($fileName);
```

and I have jQuery script which calls an iframe to download the file:

```
$('body').append('<iframe class="download" src="download.php?id='+downloading+'" style="visibility:hidden;" width="0" height="0"></iframe>');
```

I downloads the file correctly, but shows an error in the console, please let me know if its fixable??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
header("Content-type: application/x-unknown"); // I always use this
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='theFilename.ext'");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: 177998"); // you might want to set this
readfile('/the/url/to/theFilename.ext');
```

This will work ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, does the Content-Length matter what size it is.. what if the file is bigger than 177998?

Comment: Set the content length to your actual content length.. to be honest - I actually removed the content length altogether and the script worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so through a convo's with vimeo, and figuring out that the problem was due to Content-Disposition: attachment. They told me this is an issue that is inherit with browsers. You are not supposed to use a different DNS for loading resources, so it will work but the browsers won't be happy about it.