# Frame load interrupted when downloading excel files

Tags: angularjs, safari

I have an Angular script which goes to my server and grabs some data. The call looks like the following:

```
    $http.post(url).success(function(response) {
        // Do some work...

        // Go to the link that the server provided
        window.location.href = response.link;
    });
```

So the user will then be redirected to download the file (the file is hosted on S3). The file downloading and everything works...but in Safari I get the following in my console:

```
Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted
```

This is despite the fact that the file was downloaded **successfully**! Is there anything i'm missing here? No other browser has this error, however, even in Safari, the file downloads and I still get the error.

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359600/failed-to-load-resource-frame-load-interrupted-agian

Comment: @KVISH - did you get a solution for this? I am using javascript.

Comment: Nope. No solution yet.

Comment: @KVISH please keep me updated. This is 2015, I hope you found a solution already.

Comment: None. I just changed my code to not have to do it this way.