# Failed to load Resources error while downloading from safari ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, safari

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5, and I'm facing error while downloading a file from Safari, it works correctly on FireFox/Chrome.

in my website i'm trying to download xls files, which shows the error(from Safari)

> [Error] Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted

and this is my code snippet

```
var memStream = new  MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(model.ExportGenericHtml(true)));
           HttpResponseMessage fullResponse = >Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
           fullResponse.Content = new StreamContent(memStream);
           fullResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = _XlmediaType;
        // Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
           fullResponse.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Length",  memStream.Length.ToString());
           string fileName = "transactions.xls";
           fullResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("fileName") { FileName = fileName };
           fullResponse.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", fileName);
           return fullResponse;
```

Any way to solve this error?

Comment: do you use an anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

Check these params:

from [Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted - Agian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359600/failed-to-load-resource-frame-load-interrupted-agian)

```
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
header("Content-type: application/x-unknown"); // I always use this
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='theFilename.ext'");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: 177998"); // you might want to set this
```

Obviously the content type in the above answer doesn't match your needs, but the other params should be verified.